# How do I get my observable to have it's values for use in an NGRX effect

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, angular9, rxjs-observables

To be honest I am a total noob at NGRX and only limited experience in rxjs.  But essentially I have code similar to this:

```
@Effect()
applyFilters = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType<ApplyFilters>(MarketplaceActions.ApplyFilters),
withLatestFrom(this.marketplaceStore.select(appliedFilters),
  this.marketplaceStore.select(catalogCourses)),
withLatestFrom(([action, filters, courses]) => {
  return [courses,
    this.combineFilters([
      this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.TRAINING_TYPE),
      this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.INDUSTRIES)
      ])
  ];
}),
map(([courses, filters]) => {
  console.log('[applyFilters effect] currently applied filters =>', filters);

  console.log('courseFilters', filters);
  const filteredCourses = (courses as ShareableCourse[]).filter(x => (filters as number[]).includes(+x.id));
  console.log('all', courses);
  console.log('filtered', filteredCourses);

  return new SetCatalogCourses(filteredCourses);
})
);
```

Helper method:

```
private combineFilters(observables: Observable<number[]>[]): number[] {
if (!observables.some(x => x)) {
  return [];
} else {
  let collection$ = (observables[0]);
  const result: number[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < observables.length; i++) {
    if (i >= 1) {
      collection$ = concat(collection$, observables[i]) as Observable<number[]>;
    }
  }

  collection$.subscribe((x: number[]) => x.forEach(y => result.push(y)));
  return result;
}
```

}

So essentially the store objects gets populated, I can get them.  I know that the observables of 'this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(args)' do work as on the console log of the 'filters' they are there.  But the timing of the operation is wrong.  I have been reading up and am just lost after trying SwitchMap, MergeMap, Fork.  Everything seems to look okay but when I am trying to actually traverse the collections for the result of the observables from the service they are not realized yet.  I am willing to try anything but in the simplest form the problem is this:

Two observables need to be called either in similar order or pretty close.  Their 'results' are of type number[].  A complex class collection that has a property of 'id' that this number[] should be able to include.  This works just fine when all the results are not async or in a component.(I event dummied static values with variables to check my 'filter' then 'includes' logic and it works) But in NGRX I am kind of lost as it needs a return method and I am simply not good enough at rxjs to formulate a way to make it happy and ensure the observables are fully realized for their values from services to be used appropriately.  Again I can see that my console log of 'filters' is there.  Yet when I do a 'length' of it, it's always zero so I know somewhere there is a timing problem.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is `getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType` a method that calls some sort of possibly remote service which returns an `Observable<number[]>` of courseIds? If. the previous is true, do you want to concatenate the results of the 2 calls you make?

Comment: @Picci Correct.  Those methods get a number array and I would like to combine and ensure they are subscribed to for the end effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, you may want to try to substitute this

```
withLatestFrom(([action, filters, courses]) => {
  return [courses,
    this.combineFilters([
      this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.TRAINING_TYPE),
      this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.INDUSTRIES)
      ])
  ];
}),
```

with something like this

```
switchMap(([action, filters, courses]) => {
  return forkJoin(
     this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.TRAINING_TYPE),
     this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.INDUSTRIES
  ).pipe(
     map(([trainingFilters, industryFilters]) => {
        return [courses, [...trainingFilters, ...industryFilters]]
     })
}),
```

Now some explanations.

When you exit this

```
withLatestFrom(this.marketplaceStore.select(appliedFilters),
  this.marketplaceStore.select(catalogCourses)),
```

you pass to the next operator this array `[action, filters, courses]`.

The next operator has to call some remote APIs and therefore has to create a new Observable. So you are in a situation when an upstream Observable notifies something which is taken by an operator which create a **new Observable**. Similar situations are where operators such as `switchMap`, `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`), `concatMap` and `exhastMap` have to be used. Such operators *flatten* the inner Observable and return its result. This is the reason why I would use one of these flattening operators. Why `switchMap` in your case? It is not really a short story. Maybe [reading this](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) can cast some light.

Now let's look at the function passed to `switchMap`

```
return forkJoin(
         this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.TRAINING_TYPE),
         this.getCourseIdsFromFiltersByFilterType(filters, CatalogFilterType.INDUSTRIES
      ).pipe(
         map(([trainingFilters, industryFilters]) => {
            return [courses, [...trainingFilters, ...industryFilters]]
         })
```

This function first executes 2 remote API calls in parallel via `forkJoin`, then take the result of these 2 calls and map it to a new Array containing both `courses` and the concatenation of `trainingFilters` and `industryFilters`

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly thank you.  The combo of SwitchMap with Forkjoin with a pipe into a map still eludes me 'getting' it fully.  What you say makes sense but I am more of C# developer and just need to do it more to fully get 'when' to use the different methods you described like switchMap, mergeMap, and exhaustMap.  Thanks!

Comment: You may [read this](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) to see if you get a bit more clarity around Observables used with remote APIs